# Problem finding an url within html--with regex?

Tags: java, regex

```
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {//reads html page
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("https://secure\\.runescape\\.com/m=displaynames/s=[a-zA-Z1-9*]+/check_name\\.ws\\?displayname=");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                if (m.find()) {
                    System.out.println(m.group(0));
                }

            }
```

The string in the page looks like: `callback_request("https://secure.runescape.com/m=displaynames/s=p2FAuYaMFDgzntbDei*324JUo*3ozJ7hR*h1KNlxc6kPaBeKCBrdKH5kzljYSfUa/check_name.ws?displayname=" + escape(text), handleResult);`

However it's not returning any results.  Am I doing something wrong?  Apologies for the noobish question, I'm still learning java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your regular expression you are missing a `?` in the test expression.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("https://secure\\.runescape\\.com/m=displaynames/.*/check_name\\.ws\\?displayname=(\\?)?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("callback_request(\"https://secure.runescape.com/m=displaynames/s=p2FAuYaMFDgzntbDei*324JUo*3ozJ7hR*h1KNlxc6kPaBeKCBrdKH5kzljYSfUa/check_name.ws?displayname=\" + escape(text), handleResult);");
        if(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose in the `displayname=?` the ending `?` is coming from the `escape(text)` therefore if you make the `?` in the `displayname=?` as optional then it would work. Check the above code for more detail.

**>>Output:** `https://secure.runescape.com/m=displaynames/s=p2FAuYaMFDgzntbDei*324JUo*3ozJ7hR*h1KNlxc6kPaBeKCBrdKH5kzljYSfUa/check_name.ws?displayname=`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex tester for debugging, for instance [here](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm). A better expression is probably `https://secure\.runescape\.com/m=displaynames/s=[a-zA-Z1-9*]+/check_name\.ws\?displayname=`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your regex is being matched on one line at a time. Are you sure that the URL you are searching for will always be on one line?